# Where statement in foreach loop, comparing dates

Tags: powershell

Trying to import a list of users with Name, Email, Termination Date, Stop Date and first check if either stop date or termination date has passed.

Tried adding [datetime] and using get-date $user.'stop date' but without any luck.
It seems to work with the below code without the same issues though, or I get the same error, but it does check and write out that one of the values is greater:

```
$StopFolder = Get-ChildItem C:\test\123\*.csv |sort LastWriteTime -descending|select -first 1
$Stoplist = Import-Csv $StopFolder -delimiter ';'

$CurrentDate = Get-Date
foreach($Date in $Stoplist){
if($CurrentDate -eq (get-date $Date.'Stop Date')){write-host Equal}

if($CurrentDate -gt (get-date $Date.'Stop Date')){write-host Greater}

if($CurrentDate -lt (get-date $Date.'Stop Date')){write-host Less}}
```

But the same didn't seem to work for the below and can't really figure out why. I think I need to convert it to a date, but not sure why it's working in the above and not the below, nor how exactly to convert it if get-date doesn't work.

```
$StopFolder = Get-ChildItem C:\test\123\*.csv |sort LastWriteTime -descending|select -first 1
$Stoplist = Import-Csv $StopFolder -delimiter ';'
$CurrentDate = Get-Date

foreach($User in $Stoplist|where($_.'stop date' -lt $CurrentDate)){

try{
    $Usermail = $User.'e-mail address'
    $Username = get-aduser -Filter "EmailAddress -eq '$Usermail'" -properties Enabled


        if($Username.enabled){
        echo $Username 'still exists and is NOT disabled' >> C:\NotDisabled.txt
        }

        if($Username.enabled -eq $false){
        echo $Username 'still exists and is disabled' >> C:\NotDeleted.txt 
        }
}
catch{continue}
}
```

Expected result is to have it only initiate the loop if the current users stop date is less than the current date. Currently nothing happens, removing the where part and the rest seems to run fine.

Any help is much appreciated.

Edit:
CSV dates are like this:

stop date

```
01-02-2023
21-09-2019
21-01-2019
01-01-2019
01-01-2019
```

Comment: replace `$_` with `$user`? Or put brackets around the `$stoplist | where...`. I have to admit this  is a creative use of a `where` in a `foreach` since `where` is a kind of `foreach` just with filter...

Comment: It all depends on the date format used in your CSV. If you show us that, we can tell you how to convert the `$_.'stop date'` to a valid DateTime object for comparison against `$CurrentDate`.

Comment: Tried that already, no errors but no output. The values in the file, for stop date are:
01-02-2023
21-09-2019
21-01-2019
01-01-2019
01-01-2019

Thanks for the help so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: the error was not just within the logic but a typo: `| where` needs curly braces > `| where {}` not parenthesis.

---

Create a date from `'stop date'`:

```
(get-date -date $_.'stop date')
```

in one line:

```
foreach($User in $Stoplist|where{(get-date -date $_.'stop date') -lt $CurrentDate}){...}
```

Here `$Stoplist|where{(get-date -date $_.'stop date') -lt $CurrentDate}` is one unit and could be encapsulated in brackets:

```
foreach($User in ($Stoplist|where{(get-date -date $_.'stop date') -lt $CurrentDate}) ){...}
```

But without brackets around `$User in $Stoplist` the pipe `|` only refers to the last object `$Stoplist`

Comment: Thanks, but same result unfortunately:"Get-Date : Cannot bind parameter 'Date' to the target. Exception setting "Date": "Cannot convert null to type "System.DateTime".""

Comment: `Get-Date -Date "21-09-2019"` works... Check your .csv and if its imported correctly. Check `$Stoplist[0].'stop date' ` and test `Get-Date -Date $Stoplist[0].'stop date' `

Comment: @MFR1988 We can see from the examples that the date format in the CSV is `dd-MM-yyyy`. However, your current system locale can default to another format, say `MM-dd-yyyy` and in that case the 
`(Get-Date -Date $_.'stop date')` will not work. It would be safer to do `[datetime]::ParseExact($User_.'stop date', 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)`.

Comment: I'm more curiouse about `Cannot convert null to type` it should be any value but NULL...

Comment: Your first comment was spot-on. In your code however, you are not using that. You should change the `$_` to `$User`. As the foreach is now, `$_` has no meaning; is `$null`

Comment: No. I mean replace the `$_.'stop date'` into **`$User.'stop date'`**. The code is using a `foreach($User in $Stoplist) {...}`, NOT a `$Stoplist | ForEach-Object {...}`. Then also use `[datetime]::ParseExact($User_.'stop date', 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null)` and Bob's your Uncle.

Comment: Yes, that works and displays the date perfectly fine. I don't think the values are the issue. Get-date also returns it in same format.
But if I run it like this the result is the same: `foreach($User in $Stoplist|where((Get-Date -Date $user.'stop date') -lt $Date)){`

@Theo I tried adding the datetime again, but not sure I'm doing it correctly:
`foreach($User in $Stoplist|where([datetime]::ParseExact(($user_.'stop date', 'dd-MM-yyyy', $null) -lt $CurrentDate))){`
My guess would be I'm doing something wrong in the above..

Comment: @MFR1988 found the problem. see edit. My example should work now. When i tested it i wrote the code myself but when i answered i copied your code... so I never got that error